# How to work Mathjax CDN script after going to different route in Meteor-React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, mathjax

CDN mathjax works on refresh or initial load but stops working after going to different route using react-router.

I have '/' and '/admin' route.
I put script in `<head>`.
I used `$.getScript()` in client startup function.
I used `$.getScript()` in constructor() of 'Home' class page.

I used AsciiMath notations `...` inside html tags.

```
<div>`x = (-b +- sqrt(b^2-4ac))/(2a)`</div>
```

How to make Mathjax work after navigating to different route?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the docs at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html? Share a sample of what you've tried.

Comment: thanks for link. I was able to fix it by adding `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"MathExample"]);` inside `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()`